# Renaming .msi and setup.exe with project version number

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, windows-installer, installation, post-build-event

This is about a Visual Studio 2008 Setup and Deployment project.

I would like to add the project version number to the .msi file name (and to the setup.exe).  For example,

```
"MyApp.msi" -> "MyApp 3.0.1.msi"
"setup.exe" -> "MyApp 3.0.1 setup.exe"
```

I'm trying to do it in a Post-build Event, but the only macros that appear to be available to me are:

```
$(BuildOutputPath)
$(Configuration)
$(ProjectDir)
```

I tried using $(Version), but that "macro" resolves to nothing.

Is there a way to get the version number into my list of available Post-build Event macros?

Or is there some other way to accomplish this?